# How to prewhiten univariate time series?

Tags: r, time-series, white-noise

This is what I have tried so far

```
> x <- scan('d65536.txt')
Read 65535 items
> x <- ts(x)
> a <- ar(x,oreder.max=2, aic=FALSE ,method=c("yule-walker"), demean=TRUE)$resid
```

I have residuals and what should be my next step?

Comment: It is better to include a description of what you have done for those who are not familiar with the specific programming language you are using (here presumably R).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-whitening is used to help in the identification of a relation between two time series. So your next step should be to apply your obtained AR model to another time series y of interest to relate to your input x. If this is the case,

1) You can use the function *filter* from the **R stats** package.

Name: a_model, the model you fitted for your input x.

`a_model <- ar(x,order.max=2, aic=FALSE ,method="yule-walker", demean=TRUE)`

To illustrate, suppose a_model gives a AR(2) model with phi1 = `0.6`, phi2 = `-0.3`; the output y can be pre-whitened with the *filter* function:

`b <- filter(y, method="convolution", filter=c(1, -0.6, 0.3), sides = 1)`.

You could then ask for the cross-correlation between the residuals of the pre-whitened x and the series b.

2) You could also use the *prewhiten* function from the TSA package to transform both series (x, y) and obtain the sample cross-correlation function between the two pre-whitened series.

`TSA::prewhiten(x, y, x.model = a_model)`

Comment: I might well have missed something thing, but, shouldn't `method="recursive"` given it is `AR`?

Comment: and given `filter` is reverse time order, I believe `filter=c(.3, -.6, 1)` as well?

Comment: @stucash. Maybe I am a little late here, but hoping to be of help anyway. The mathematical expression of an Autoregressive model is a convolution. The recursive method is used with a moving average model. As to the order of the parameters of the model, they are always in reverse order of the data: time t first, t-1, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use functions in forecast library to pre-whiten y, using a fitted arima model of x. For example: (fill p, d, q, P, D, Q in `arima` function or use other functions, like `auto.arima` to fit an arima model for x)

```
library(forecast)
mod_1 <- arima(x, order = c(1, 1, 1), seasonal = list(order = c(1, 1, 1), period = 12), include.mean = T)
y <- y - fitted(Arima(y, model = mod_1))
ccf(x, y)
```

You can also do:

```
y <- residuals(Arima(y, model = mod_1))
```

You can check whether the pre-whitening method works by:

```
sum(x - mod1$residuals) < 10^6
```

Why I use the above method is that I don't know how to use `filter` when there is the MA (Moving Average) part. Additionally, there may be some problems when using `prewhiten` from "TSA" package. See [Prewhiten in R gives “all times contain an NA”, but there are no NA values in the time series](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55773581/10181743).

Answer (score 0):

For prewhitening of univariate time series, you can use *prewhiten* function from `psd` package. e.g.
`prewhiten(ts(x), AR.max=10, zero.pad="rear")`
where AR.max is the maximum AR order to fit.